# Две модели в одной ActiveForm Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Привет!
Есть такая проблема, читал на форумах как положить 2 модели в одну ActiveForm, но так и не смог понять как это сделать.

Код:

1. Модель

   ```
   <?php
   namespace app\models;
   use Yii;
   use yii\gii\CodeFile;


   class BookingHall extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
   {
      public $date_range;
      /**
       * @inheritdoc
       */
      public static function tableName()
      {
          return 'booking_hall';
      }
      /**
       * @inheritdoc
       */
      public function rules()
      {
       return [
       [['user_id', 'admin_id', 'hall_id', 'seatings_id', 'languege_id', 'transport', 'registration', 'baij', 'translators', 'translators_from_id', 'translators_to_id', 'audio', 'photo', 'people', 'dateStart', 'dateEnd', 'duration', 'breakfast_count', 'lunch_count', 'dinner_count', 'env_1', 'env_2', 'env_3', 'env_4', 'env_5', 'env_6', 'env_7', 'env_8', 'env_9', 'env_10', 'env_11', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
       [['user_id', 'people', 'dateStart', 'dateEnd', 'time', 'duration', 'name', 'date_range',], 'required'],
       [['time'], 'safe'],
       [['additional', 'status'], 'string'],
       [['price'], 'number'],
       [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],

       ['languege_id', 'default', 'value' => 0],
       ['user_id', 'default', 'value' => 0],
       ['admin_id', 'default', 'value' => 0],
       ['translators_from_id', 'default', 'value' => 0],
       ['translators_to_id', 'default', 'value' => 0],
       ['breakfast_count', 'default', 'value' => 0],
       ['lunch_count', 'default', 'value' => 0],
       ['dinner_count', 'default', 'value' => 0],

       [['translators_from_id', 'translators_to_id'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
           return $model->translators == 1;
       }, 'whenClient'              => "function (attribute, value) {
               return $('#translators').is(':checked');
           }",
         ],
       ];
       }
   }
   ```

Вторая модель

```
    <?php

    namespace backend\models;
    use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;
    use Yii;
    /**
     * This is the model class for table "booking_hall_env".
     *
     * @property integer $id
     * @property string $booking_hall_id
     * @property string $environment_id
     */
class BookingHallEnv extends ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'booking_hall_env';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['booking_hall_id', 'environment_id'], 'required'],
        [['booking_hall_id', 'environment_id'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'booking_hall_id' => 'Booking Hall ID',
        'environment_id' => 'Environment ID',
    ];
}

}
```

Контроллер :

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $date = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('date', date('Y-m-d'));
    $hall_id = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('hall_id', 0);

    $model = new BookingHall();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        preg_match_all('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) - (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $model->date_range, $maches);

        if (!empty($maches[1][0]) && !empty($maches[2][0])) {

            $model->setAttributes([
                'dateStart' => strtotime($maches[1][0]),
                'dateEnd'   => strtotime($maches[2][0]),
            ]);
        }

        $model->setAttributes([
            'admin_id'   => \Yii::$app->user->id,
            'created_at' => time(),
            'updated_at' => time(),
        ]);

        $model->price = $model->getPrice();

        if ($model->save()) {

            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }

    if (empty($model->date_range)) {

        $model->date_range = $date . ' - ' . $date;
    }

    if ($hall_id) {

        $model->hall_id = $hall_id;
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Вьюха там обычная,
не могу понять как можно использовать 2 модели в одной ActiveForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно загрузили модель *BookingHall*, однако нигде не используете вторую - *BookingHallEnv*. То есть вам надо сделать примерно следующее:

```
$bookingHallModel = new BookingHall();
$bookingHallEnvModel = new BookingHallEnv();

$bookingHallModel->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post());
$bookingHallEnvModel->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post());

if (!$bookingHallModel->validate()) {
    Html::errorSummary($bookingHallModel);
}

if (!$bookingHallEnvModel->validate()) {
    Html::errorSummary($bookingHallEnvModel);
}
```

Таким образом вы получите данные из формы для разных моделей.